# Basics of Routing in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

It is a very basic scenario but, being a beginner in `Angular 2.0`, I am having a hard time to figure out how to achieve the same.

Prior to `Routing Implementation` I would have a line like this in 
**app.component.html**

```
<app-home [selectedNinja] = "ninja" (onYell) = "yell($event)">Hello There</app-home>
```

And in **app.component.ts** I have like

```
export class AppComponent {

  ninja = {
    name : 'Yoshi',
    belt: 'Black'
  }
  ......
  ......
```

So it's an `@Input` parameter that would be accepted in our **home.component.ts** file.

Now after Routing implementation I can only have :

```
  <!--<app-home [selectedNinja] = "ninja" (onYell) = "yell($event)">Hello There</app-home>-->
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/directory" routerLinkActive="active">Directory</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So I want to load **home component** when **default route** is asked for.

But I don't know now how to pass the input data and the event like before ?

We do not have the `<app-home>` like declaration right ?

Or am I missing very basic something ?

Comment: Don't use the home component as the route's component. Use another component (let's call it actual-home), that defines the hard-coded ninja just like app does currently, and passes it the the home component from its template. Same for the event: put the yell() method in the actual-home component.

Comment: @JBNizet An example would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your home component is not really a home component. It's a ninja component: it takes a ninja as input and emits events when this ninja yells. Such a component is not a good candidate for a routing component.

So, if you want your home page to display a hard-coded ninja, create a routing component that defines this ninja, and passes it as input to your ninja component. Just like your app component does currently.

First step: rename your home component to ninja.

Second step: define a real home component:

```
@Component({
  template: '<app-ninja [selectedNinja] = "ninja" (onYell) = "yell($event)">Hello There</app-ninja>'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  ninja = {
    name : 'Yoshi',
    belt: 'Black'
  }

  yell(event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```